# Starcraft 2 - Can I rearrange the command card?

Tags: starcraft-2

For us Warcraft 3 veterans there's a huge feature in the form of a `CustomKeys` file. This feature allows us to rearrange the command card as we want, providing the best control setup that our hands enjoy.

For example, the default command card has spells on ZXCV, but I changed it to be QWER, and used ZXCV less accessible keys for less useful orders: Move, patrol, and passives in general.

With Starcraft 2 there's a grid mode that basically makes the command card become hardcoded grid mode, but most keys are very impractical and take a long time to get used to, such as T-Attack or Z-Build. I can set whatever keys I deem right using the Standard profile, but the command card stays hardcoded with the visual position of every button staying in the same place, it's not convenient for me to look at the card and see the build button at the bottom of the card, but press Q to show the building menu.

So what I want to do is basically rearrange the button positions, is this possible?

Here's an example. Assume this is the command card matrix:

```
[0,0][0,1][0,2][0,3][0,4]=[Q][W][E][R][T]
[1,0][1,1][1,2][1,3][1,4]=[A][S][D][F][G]
[2,0][2,1][2,2][2,3][2,4]=[Z][X][C][V][B]
```

By default, the Grid profile sets attack on `[0,4]` and assigns the <kbd>T</kbd> key. In Warcraft 3 I could do this:

```
[cmdattack]Tip=(|cffffcc00A|r) Attack
Hotkey=A
Buttonpos=0,1
```

Now my attack key is <kbd>A</kbd> and is positioned in the respective slot in the command card. I hope the example is clear enough.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to rearrange the command card. You would have to replace the existing hotkeys for each race individually in the options.